# MySQL: Is there a way to use window functions instead of subqueries to find average number of times an action is taken, per user?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table, named `log`, that records when a user takes one of a small number of actions; lets suppose these are actions 1 and 2, and the users may choose to repeatedly take these actions. The table has columns `username, action_time, action_done`.

I would like a result set with a column for actions, the average number of times that action was taken (per user), and max number of times any user took that action. I was able to accomplish this with what seems to be a fairly clumsy subquery:

```
SELECT   
  DISTINCT(s.action) as "Action",  
  AVG(s.times_done) OVER (PARTITION BY s.action) as "Average Times Done",  
  MAX(s.times_done) OVER (PARTITION BY s.action) as "Max Times Done"  
FROM (
SELECT action, COUNT(action)  as times_done
FROM log
GROUP BY action, username 
) s;
```

I have a rudimentary understanding of window functions, but I can't seem to get the subquery to work correctly using `COUNT` as a window function. Moreover, I feel like I should be able to accomplish this in a much simpler way, avoiding a subquery altogether. For example, if my data set were:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  username  |      action_time      |  action_done  |
======================================================
| first_user |  2020-01-30 13:01:23  |       1       |
| first_user |  2020-01-30 12:34:40  |       2       |
| first_user |  2020-01-30 12:34:56  |       2       |
| secnd_user |  2020-01-30 15:25:14  |       1       |
| secnd_user |  2020-01-30 15:25:00  |       2       |
| secnd_user |  2020-01-30 15:25:31  |       2       |
| secnd_user |  2020-01-30 15:26:02  |       2       |
```

then I would like to get the following result set:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  Action  |  Average Times Done  |  Max Times Done  |
======================================================
|    1     |           1          |        1         |
|    2     |          2.5         |        3         |
```

Can anyone make some suggestions?

**Edit**: Let me explain the data and result set a bit. I've included an ISO datetime column not because I expect it to be relevant for the ultimate goal, but because I found the data more confusing without it. Users are interacting with some website, and the database is storing who does what, and when.

So first_user does action 1 once, action 2 twice. Then second_user does action 1 once, action 2 they do 3 times.

Therefore, the average number of times my two users did action 1 is once: (1+1)/2. The average number of times my users did action two was 2.5 times: (2+3)/2.

**Second edit:** perhaps calling the actions 1 and 2 was a confusing choice. Really, it's more like there are two buttons on this website, button A and button B, and the users are clicking them. I'd like to know that across all users, people tended to click button A between 5 and 6 times, but more clicked 6 or more times, and so there would be an average of 5.72 clicks on A. Maybe one person loves button A more than anyone else, and they click it 50 times. The result row, `Action, Average Times Done, Max Times Done` for button_A would be:

```
|  A  |   5.72   |    50   |
```

Comment: The data set and expected o/p is confusing.

Comment: Please explain (for each average and max time in expected output) how does it was calculated from shown source data.

Comment: Since you can't nest aggregate/window functions, there really isn't any better way to do this.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT action_done,
                     username,
                     COUNT(action_done) cnt
              FROM actions
              GROUP BY action_done, username )
SELECT action_done `Action`,
       AVG(cnt) `Average Times Done`,
       MAX(cnt) `Max Times Done`
FROM cte
GROUP BY action_done;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e163a09de0f887223051e194cdf91b1)

Comment: That probably needs `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(action_done)`, especially since that column is in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @RickJames This makes sense only in the case when `action_done` is nullable.